# How to load a table on Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have my table of data to display automatically when you load up a page.

The only way I know is the JQuery's click function. Which just allows me to click and view the table.

How do I get my table to load automatically without a click function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code inside.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Load your table here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your code to understand exactly what you're talking about, but I assume your JQuery click function is calling a function that shows/loads the table.

So instead of calling the function within the JQuery click function, do one of these:

1. At the bottom of your body element, create a script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onLoad(yourFunction());
</script>
```

2. Call the function using onLoad within the Body tag:

```
<body onLoad="yourFunction();">
```

3. Use JQuery's `$(document).ready()` functionality

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/